# Is PhantomJS able to work with WebWorkers?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, web-worker

Everytime when I try to test Web Worker via [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) it gives me an error:

> SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through
>   the security policy of the user agent.

Does it mean that PhantomJS isn't able to work with WebWorkers or I need to set some configuration to make it work?

E.g. I need to test a script which interacts with WebWorker (in my case **worker.js** file):

```
var worker = new Worker('doWork.js');
worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  console.log('Worker said: ', e.data);
}, false);
worker.postMessage('Hello World');
phantom.exit();
```

And this is a code of Worker (**dowork.js**):

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  self.postMessage(e.data);
}, false);
phantom.exit();
```

And when I try to run it I got:

```
pavel@lenovo:~/phantom_test$ phantomjs worker.js 
SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.

  worker.js:1
```

Comment: Have you tried to run it with the `--web-security=false` commandline option?

Comment: It doesn't work, same error.

Answer (score 4):

Your script will not work with the current release of PhantomJS 2.
I assume you're using PhantomJS 2 (but this applies to PhantomJS 1 too).

We had an issue when the main execution context didn't respect `web-security` option. And the fix for it was recently pushed (see https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/commit/d938eddaf2039cc4d8a90704f736129edb8e1260)

So, you have to wait for 2.0.1 release or build PhantomJS 2 from sources.